# how to know from where the web page(url) is coming in jsp and send processed data to that page?

Tags: java, html, jsp

When I click  link I have to pop-up a window which will accept some details and send back processed data to that page.

Comment: say for example, home.jsp has that link, after pressing process.jsp is opened. after submit button in process.jsp , processed data should reflect on home.jsp..>

Answer (score 0):

You can set some fort of parameter to request and use the same in the pop-up

eg :

In Parent page:

```
<%    request.setAttribute("someVariable",request.getRequestURI()); %>
```

in the child

```
<% String oldUrl = (String)request.getAttribute("someVariable");
```

Answer (score 0):

with using bootstrap you can do this way.....

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#password">I forgot my password</a>

//------------bootstrap modal--------------

<div class="modal fade" id="password" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Enter Mail</h4> 
  </div>
  <div class=" modal-body">
    <form action="forgot_password.php"   method="POST" >

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Mail Id:</label>
        <input type="mail" name="mail"  class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
  <input type="submit" value="Send"  class="btn btn-primary">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```